# Calculate distance between list of origin-destination using google api

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

I have a requirement to calculate the distance between the list of origin and destinations.

Say list has o1-d1, o2-d2, o3-d3 etc.

Is there a way to send all at a time to Google API and get all results instead of single o-d iterating in a loop for the size of the list.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that the answers is NO.

For now the API is design to give you only this format of response and the way to go is parsing throw it [1].

[1]https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_parsing_the_results